# SELECT STATEMENT Join Fact to Dimension but return only unique values

Tags: sql

I'm not the DBA so I don't have control over the schema structure of our dataset. There are 2 critical data points that are missing in our product fact table and so I have to join to a many dimension in order to get those 2 additional columns.  The problem I'm having is the one to many relationship is producing duplicate records in the output, increasing from 80,000 records to upwards of 14M - down to 330,000 if I add DISTINCT:

```
SELECT a.key, a.fact, a.fact2, a.fact3, b.dynamic1, b.dynamic2, a.adnausium
FROM ProductTable a 
LEFT JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT key, dynamic1, dynamic2 FROM DynamicTable) b
ON a.key = b.key
```

Is there a better way to SELECT to reduce the output to just the original FACT table length?

Comment: a full [mre] would help understand your problem also please tag your database

Answer (score 0):

use simple

```
SELECT a.key, a.fact, a.fact2, a.fact3,
(select top 1 dynamic1 from DynamicTable where a.key=key) dynamic1, 
(select top 1 dynamic2 from DynamicTable where a.key=key) dynamic2, a.adnausium
FROM ProductTable a
```